# Using Multiple Kafka Listeners to handle specific data types on a shared topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have two kafka listeners A & B that are each in separate services listening to the same topic. Listener A only cares about data types 1, 2 & 3 while Listener B only cares about data type 3. I was considering using individual `@KafkaHandler` methods to handle the different data types. However, my concern is about what will happen if listener B receives data types 1 or 2? Is an error thrown ? Does it safely ignore.

Also wanted to double confirm but, messages of the same type like data type 3 should be consumed by both listeners so long as the consumer group-id is different.

```
@KafkaListener
public class listenerA {
    @KafkaHandler
    public void dataType1(Object1 data) { ... }
    @KafkaHandler
    public void dataType2(Object2 data) { ... }
    @KafkaHandler
    public void dataType3(Object3 data) { ... }
}
```

```
@KafkaListener
public class listenerB {
    @KafkaHandler
    public void dataType3(Object3 data) { ... }
}
```

Comment: An error should be thrown by the internal deserializer, yes, but this depends on how you configured your consumer factory. Please share your configs

Comment: As long as the deserializer can handle them, you can configure a filter to discard the unwanted records. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `RecordFilterStragegy` in the second listener container to discard unwanted types.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages

Comment: Nice thank you. Could data overhead be a concern if we are sending a lot of datatypes then, end up getting filtered out ?

Comment: Yes, clearly it would be best to use a different topic for each type, unless the volume is low.

Comment: Originally, I was trying to go with an individual kafka partition approach on the same topic & we could assign a listener to only listen to a specific partitions that way it could be more scalable as data types grow. However, I quickly found out that that disables group rebalance ? & that I might need to manage the offset myself which sounded like a big hassle

Comment: You can still use the group for offset commit tracking without using group management (for partition balancing) (`group.id` servers 2 purposes) See it's docs `This property is required if the consumer uses either the group management functionality by using <code>subscribe(topic)</code> or the Kafka-based offset management strategy."`. Just manually assign partitions that contain Object3 to `listenerB`. It's ok if you have complete control over the producers and can be sure they will not cross post records to the wrong partition(s). It's a bit more tricky if you need to add partitions later.

Comment: I tried manually assigning partitions to a single listener but, my service continues to fail ever 9 mins (the default timelimit for the *connections_max_idle_ms* property). The exact error is basically these 3 lines repeating over & over every 9mins:

* Discovered group coordinator 
* Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator
* Group coordinator is unavailable or invalid due to cause:
coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.

I was able to resolve by setting the kafka property `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1` but, I am hesitant to do that

Comment: Doesn't sound right; maybe ask a new question here or on one of the Kafka mailing lists. I don't recall seeing such problems with manual assignment.